# undefined method `course' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

#routes.rb

```
  resources :courses do

      resources :chapters

  end
```

chapter/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Chapters</h1>

<table class="table table table-striped table table-hover"> 
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Chapter no</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @chapters.each do |chapter| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= chapter.title %></td>
        <td><%= chapter.chapter_no %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', course_chapter_path(course_id: chapter.course.id, id: chapter.id) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_course_chapter_path(course_id: chapter.course.id, id: chapter.id) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', course_chapter_path(course_id: chapter.course.id, id: chapter.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Chapter', new_course_chapter_path(course_id: @chapter.course.id, id: @chapter.id), class: 'btn btn-secondary' %>
```

I am getting an error in last line of chapters/index.html.erb
I have been practicing nested routing and trying get my head around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <%= link_to 'New Chapter', new_course_chapter_path(course_id: params[:course_id]), class: 'btn btn-secondary' %>
```

For new object(chapter), you don't need to pass chapter id because you are creating new object(chapter).

Note: Here I am assuming, you are getting course id from params.

Comment: Still not wroking
```
@course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
```
I am passing this from chapter controller

Comment: Once try with params[:id] and even if its not working, please provide your controller index method

Comment: It is working now. Thank you. I did not put "@course = Course.find(params[:course_id])" in my index. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

refer to new action route

```
new_course_chapter GET /courses/:course_id/chapters/new(.:format) chapters#new
```

For new action you should provide course_id without id of chapter

```
<%= link_to 'New Chapter', new_course_chapter_path(course_id: params[:course_id]), class: 'btn btn-secondary' %>
```

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"chapters", :course_id=>nil}, possible unmatched constraints: [:course_id]

Getting this error

Comment: what url you use for index page? you should use something like this /courses/1/chapters